# Extract phases from a tagged sentence in python

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Given a tagged sentence in Chinese

```
令#VV 客户#NN 印象#NN 深刻#VA 的#DEC 事情#NN 就是#AD 感觉#VV 经销店#NN 整体#NN 的#DEG 员工#NN 对#P 客户#NN 都#AD 不错#VA
```

I need to extract phases like

```
客户#NN 印象#NN 深刻#VA
客户#NN 都#AD 不错#VA
```

The rule is phases must begin with one or more `#NN`, then followed by zero or multiple `#AD`, and ends with a `#VA`. And if there are more than one matched phases in a given sentence, I need all shortest phases returned.

Can anyone suggest a regex pattern, or a piece of code if it's not possible to do this in one single statement. Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample input/output of your question.

Comment: Why isn't `都#AD 不错#VA` included as solution?

Comment: you can use `split('#NN')` to convert string into array

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I've solved this by using nltk chunking.

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense, the first phrase example you gave doesn't fit your rule.

Comment: @zyxue, sorry for confusing. You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = [('令', 'VV'), ('客户', 'NN'), ('印象', 'NN'), ('深刻', 'VA'), ('的', 'DEC'), ('事情', 'NN'), ('就是', 'AD'), ('感觉', 'VV'), ('经销店', 'NN'), ('整体', 'NN'), ('的', 'DEG'), ('员工', 'NN'), ('对', 'P'), ('客户', 'NN'), ('都', 'AD'), ('不错', 'VA')]
grammer = 'NP: {<NN>+<AD>*<VA>}'
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammer)
result = cp.parse(sentence)
result.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Comment: To reiterate, what @shA.t meant to say, it is that you should upvote and accept the answer if the answer is "exactly what you want" =)